Local surrogate models explained via differential geometry
The following is the definition of a local surrogate model given in this blog here:

Local surrogate models are interpretable models that are used to explain individual predictions of black box machine learning models.

Very often one chooses a linear model as the interpretable model.
Hence, the idea is to assume that our black box behaves locally as a linear model and we then find the linear model that fits best.
The linear model to explain the result of the vector $\vec x$ that contains the data of our observation does not necessary match the linear model that explains the result for another data-point $\vec{x}'$.
Now, this picture resembles that of differential geometry, where the space is assumed to be smooth so that a tangent plane at each of its points exists, and of course tangent points at different point still be different. Therefore the question:

Is there any approach to local surrogate models that uses this formalism of differential geometry?

I would like to see how all these concepts are defined rigorously on manifolds.
EDIT:
I have found this question on MO that has an answer towards the direction I want. I would like to get others as well.

This is maybe not an answer to your question, but it might be related. In control engineering, dynamic systems can be analyzed in their differential form, yielding quasi linear models. The variations are then embedded as a linear parameter-varying model (the surrogate model) that varies in a convex set (so you trade a bit of conservatism for linear compute). A nice PhD thesis on this topic: https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/266380728/20230215_Koelewijn_hf.pdf Maybe this sparks some ideas?

Of course @seaver. Thank you very much!!
